# sega-genesis and sega-mega-drive should be tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I recently created the [sega-genesis](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sega-genesis) tag for [this question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1514/621).  As per Robotnik's comment, I think a [sega-mega-drive](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sega-mega-drive) tag should also be created and made a synonym of [sega-genesis](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sega-genesis).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems sensible - I've done this.

Incidentally, users with 1250 total reputation and 5 in the tag can vote for synonyms. Four votes and the synonym is created without moderator intervention.  Details [here](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms).

(I know for a new tag nobody will have the 5 in the tag yet)